# What is the use of First() and Follow() in compiler design?

Tags: compilers, parsers

I am completely aware of how to calculate first and follow, my professor has taught me that well , but he had not explained what is the need of First() and Follow(), so any explanation why we need them will help me very much.

Comment: FYI, there's a [really good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20317336/6243352) to this over on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

$FIRST$ and $FOLLOW$ sets are used by the algorithm which produces an $LL(k)$ parser from a grammar. They're also used in a number of other algorithms which analyze grammars, but most students will run into them when learning about top-down parsers.

Parsing is a tiny part of the work of producing a compiler, and in practice you can generate a parser using code-generation tools which avoid you having to know much about implementation details. So I'd say that th4e direct answer to your question is that $FIRST$ and $FOLLOW$ sets have very little to do with compiler *design*, but they are useful in the understanding of how particular parsing algorithms work.

Answer (score 0):

$FIRST$ of a non-terminal would refer to the very first character of the strings that can be derived starting from that non-terminal. The $FIRST$ of a terminal would be the terminal itself.

The $FOLLOW$ of a non-terminal $A$ refers to the $FIRST$ of the non-terminal or terminal that immediately comes after $A$ in the dervivation rules.

They are used by parsing algorithms to determine which production to use for parsing a string. If we have a choice of multiple productions, and we wish to generate a string $x$ we would like to use the productions that can generate strings that start with $x$. This is where $FIRST$ can be used to identify such productions.

Comment: why are they important? what are there importance in compiling?

Comment: I have edited the answer